# crypto-js decrypt from Hex

Tags: aes, cryptojs

I am trying to make a JavaScript function with package crypto-js to decode AES (CBC mode).

I input the data in an online decoding tool and it decrypted correctly, so I am sure the following data is correct, but I just can't reproduce it by JavaScript.

Here is the online decrypting (so I'm sure the data, key, iv are correct): http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/link/deb718giF4dUxZylq/

My code with crypto-js@3.1.8:

```
// data, key, iv are all Hex
var data = "bd6e0a73147a2c224c7c20346d0e9a138b744a5d94463cdff6dbb965055f974f097104399d2c40af2f0ac667f3857e70e9703bf27f6411f7e97c3449e8921f3c98e665914689b4b77b5bbcc8d8bc319e680eb89eedb1c25178923ae57fb3fb476755d6009f1aed88fffcb9b2ed3b4cf6f23d9c4c56da1dde6619e45a8d6f06412853ae1941cf554b6824112a913750a7485ed67fb38b950411310410de998f2597c2fcc81a305b0df369f54b75426176";
var key = 'befce5c6da98837ea421811c832817ae';
var iv = "a884a7edd5d06a48d6da9ad11fd36a75";
// transfer Hex to WordArray
var _data = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(data);
var base64_data = _data.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
var _key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);
var _iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv);

decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
  base64_data, // pass base64
  _key,  // pass WordArray
  {iv: _iv, // pass WordArray
   mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
   padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
  })
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
// out put fail to match Utf8
```

It output Error: Malformed UTF-8 data

The decoded string should be: (the link is not important)

```
https://emogo-media-testing.s3.amazonaws.com/1503342403787_blob?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI5MUDCK6XYWKGAKA&Expires=1534882403&Signature=t1PFesQuOpOlIMKoOqje%2Bs7I%2Fhg
```

Any hint is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it has been a while since you asked the question but I will respond just so the next person does not stumble upon an unanswered question.

Your code works fine, it decrypts AES.CBC encrypted data correct, the problem lies with your input `data`.

Your encrypted `data` string should have looked like:

```
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
```

for this example to work correctly.

The key you used is not a hex string but a text string. Your online example is no longer valid but I figured it out after a couple of tries.

If change the following line:

```
var _key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);
```

to:

```
var _key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
```

Your code example will work fine with your original data string.

When you decrypted the text on http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/ you probably had the plaintext textbox selected instead of hex for your key input.